# Can I use preventDefault to my event with passive equal true?

Tags: javascript, events, preventdefault

I've came across to the next [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/inside-browser-part4#be_aware_when_you_write_event_handlers), there I found example with blocking scroll event:

```
document.body.addEventListener('pointermove', event => {
  if (event.cancelable) {
      event.preventDefault(); // block the native scroll
      /*
      *  do what you want the application to do here
      */
  }
}, {passive: true});
```

but, it doesn't work, by the way I see illogicality using `preventDefault` in `passive: true` event. What is going on, anyone would explain to me?

Comment: *"...there I found example with blocking scroll event."* I assume you meant a **non**-blocking scroll event handler.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder nope, this is exactly **blocking** event handler. That's why I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's the point of `passive`. From [MDN's documentation for `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> **`passive`**
>
> A boolean value that, if `true`, indicates that the function specified by listener will never call `preventDefault()`. If a passive listener does call `preventDefault()`, the user agent will do nothing other than generate a console warning. See [Improving scrolling performance with passive listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners) to learn more.

And similarly, from [the specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-addeventlisteneroptions-passive):

> When set to `true`, `options`’s `passive` indicates that the callback will not cancel the event by invoking `preventDefault()`. This is used to enable performance optimizations described in [§ 2.8 Observing event listeners](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#observing-event-listeners).

The article would appear to be mistaken, or referring to situations that are not yet standardized (as they mention something about horizontal scrolling being underway while vertical scrolling starts).

Comment: Have you read article what I pointed? My problem is that I don't understand this example. By the way look at the comments in presented code: `block the native scroll`. I am confused.

Comment: @MaximPro - I've updated the answer. As far as I can tell, the article is either mistaken, or referring to an edge case that is not (yet/) covered by the specification.

Comment: This is weird situation. Article has been written in 2018, many years have passed. It's very-very strange. Wait, it's google's article, so what is wrong with it?

Comment: @MaximPro - Everyone at Google is not infallible. Errors can occur, edits gone awry, etc. But I've [reached out](https://twitter.com/tjcrowder/status/1487409866859814914) to Jake Archibald, one of Google's lead devrel people, asking for clarification.

Comment: Wow, nice to hear it. Let me know what he will have answered. It's interesting thing. Also will track your tweet :)

Comment: @MaximPro - My guess is it's just a mistake, but you never know...